# Vulkan Ray Tracing (VK_KHR_ray_tracing) - доступ к атрибутам вершин

Tags: c++, vulkan, raytracing

Пытаюсь осилить трассировку лучей на Vulkan, основной источник информации - [этот туториал](https://nvpro-samples.github.io/vk_raytracing_tutorial_KHR/). Разобрался с построением BLAS и TLAS, создал таблицу SBT и в итоге наконец дошел до трассировки сцены:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собирался уже переходить к реализации простенького освещения, и тут возник вопрос, ответ на которой в туториале я найти не смог..

**Как получить атрибуты вершин?**

Меня во всём этом больше всего смущает следующее:

1. В моем рендрере, который изначально делался под растеризатор, сцена описывается набором мешей, где каждый меш обладает своим вершинным и индексным буфером.
2. В случае с трассировкой лучей, данные буферы используются как основа для BLAS (структур ускорения нижнего уровня), но BLAS содержит ТОЛЬКО положения, и доступа к атрибутам из BLAS нет.
3. Есть TLAS (структура ускорения верхнего уровня), которая, по сути, описывает сцену для рей-трейсинга. Там есть такое понятие как instance, который уже ссылается на BLAS (то есть, то что сцена может описываться МНОЖЕСТВОМ разных буферов, а не одним единственным, как бы уже подразумевается)
4. При всём при этом, по атрибуты вершин отдельных instance нигде ничего не сказано, и максимум что шейдер может получить во время пересечения это барицентрические координаты и некий `gl_PrimitiveID` (я так понимаю, хранящий индекс треугольника), а также `gl_InstanceID` (я так понимаю индекс instance'a в TLAS)

Это всё пораждает следующие вопросы:

1. Значит ли всё это что мне нужно геометрию повторно загружать в какой-то SSBO чтобы получить доступ к атрибутам вершин.
2. Если таки да, то если у меня сцена описывается РАЗНЫМИ буферами вершин, а не один большим, что в таком случае делать? Получается нужно создавать какой-то двумерный массив, который будет хранится в SSBO, ключами которого будут instance id'ы?
3. Если таки да, и если такой массив сделать, значит там еще нужно хранить трансформации кроме самих вершин, для того чтобы получать актуальные значения атрибутов (например нормалей)?

В туториале, который я упоминал выше, представлен следующий код шейдера:

```
layout(binding = 2, set = 1, scalar) buffer ScnDesc { sceneDesc i[]; } scnDesc;
layout(binding = 5, set = 1, scalar) buffer Vertices { Vertex v[]; } vertices[];
layout(binding = 6, set = 1) buffer Indices { uint i[]; } indices[];

// Object of this instance
uint objId = scnDesc.i[gl_InstanceID].objId;

// Indices of the triangle
ivec3 ind = ivec3(indices[nonuniformEXT(objId)].i[3 * gl_PrimitiveID + 0],   //
                indices[nonuniformEXT(objId)].i[3 * gl_PrimitiveID + 1],   //
                indices[nonuniformEXT(objId)].i[3 * gl_PrimitiveID + 2]);  //
// Vertex of the triangle
Vertex v0 = vertices[nonuniformEXT(objId)].v[ind.x];
Vertex v1 = vertices[nonuniformEXT(objId)].v[ind.y];
Vertex v2 = vertices[nonuniformEXT(objId)].v[ind.z];
```

Но я не совсем понимаю что тут происходит. Что такое nonuniformEXT и зачем это? Тут также в качестве дескрипторов есть массив вершин и массив индексов.. одномерный массив.. будто бы в нем вся геометрия сцены.

В общем я совершенно запутался в этом, буду крайне благодарен если кто-то прольет свет на всё это.

Comment: nonuniformEXT - это нестандартное расширение Vulkan-диалекта glsl от nvidia, служащее для обозначения переменной или выражения, как не обладающего свойством динамической однородности, то есть что повторные вычисления этого выражения в пределах одной группы вычислений могут давать разные результаты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, всё прояснилось.

Из BLAS действительно никак нельзя извлечь атрибуты вершин, но это вовсе не означает что буферы геометрии (которые использовались для BLAS) нельзя использовать повторно, чтобы эти самые атрибуты извлечь.

Основной момент в следующем коде

```
layout(binding = 5, set = 1, scalar) buffer Vertices { Vertex v[]; } vertices[];
layout(binding = 6, set = 1) buffer Indices { uint i[]; } indices[];
```

заключается в том, что это не одномерные массивы. Это *массивы дескрипторов*. То есть каждый элемент такого массива соответствует одному буферу.

Можно привязать несколько буферов в качестве SSBO, и обращаться к ним. В качестве ключа для такого массива дескрипторов может быть использован gl_InstanceID.

Таким образом, если у нас, например, на сцене отображается 5 объектов, у каждого есть ссылка на свой буфер геометрии (вершинный и индексный буферы) - можно просто привязать 5 дескрипторов, как элементы массива.

gl_PrimitiveID - это индекс треугольника, с которым произошло пересечение луча, и его можно использовать чтобы достать нужные индексы. А уже при помощи извлеченных индексов обратиться к нужным вершинам.

**Как приготовить этот дескрипторный массив?**

1. Убеждаемся что подключены расширения устройства `VK_EXT_DESCRIPTOR_INDEXING_EXTENSION_NAME` и `VK_EXT_SCALAR_BLOCK_LAYOUT_EXTENSION_NAME`
2. Убеждаемся что включены нужные features физ. устройства при создании логического устройства:

   ```
   vk::PhysicalDeviceVulkan12Features vulkan12Features{};
   vulkan12Features.setDescriptorBindingVariableDescriptorCount(VK_TRUE);
   vulkan12Features.setRuntimeDescriptorArray(VK_TRUE);
   vulkan12Features.setDescriptorIndexing(VK_TRUE);
   vulkan12Features.setShaderStorageBufferArrayNonUniformIndexing(VK_TRUE);
   ```
3. При создании пула дескрипторов, указываем типы дескрипторов - eStorageBuffer, и кол-во, которое должно быть равно максимальному кол-ву отдельных объектов (мешей) на сцене.

   ```
    // Создать пул для набора используемого в трассировке лучей
    {
        // Размеры пула для наборов типа "набор для трассировки лучей"
        std::vector<vk::DescriptorPoolSize> descriptorPoolSizes = {
                // Дескриптор структуры ускорения верхнего уровня
                {vk::DescriptorType::eAccelerationStructureKHR, 1},
                // Дескриптор структуры итогового изображения (результат трассировки)
                {vk::DescriptorType::eStorageImage, 1},

                // Дескрипторы storage-буферов хранящих индексы (массив дескрипторов),
                {vk::DescriptorType::eStorageBuffer, static_cast<uint32_t>(maxMeshes)},
                // Дескрипторы storage-буферов хранящих вершины (массив дескрипторов)
                {vk::DescriptorType::eStorageBuffer, static_cast<uint32_t>(maxMeshes)},
                // Дескрипторы uniform-бферов хранящих матрицы трансфомацияя (массив дескрипторов)
                {vk::DescriptorType::eStorageBuffer, static_cast<uint32_t>(maxMeshes)}

        };

        // Нам нужен один набор данного типа, он будет привязываться единожды за кадр
        vk::DescriptorPoolCreateInfo descriptorPoolCreateInfo{};
        descriptorPoolCreateInfo.poolSizeCount = descriptorPoolSizes.size();
        descriptorPoolCreateInfo.pPoolSizes = descriptorPoolSizes.data();
        descriptorPoolCreateInfo.maxSets = 1;
        descriptorPoolCreateInfo.flags = vk::DescriptorPoolCreateFlagBits::eFreeDescriptorSet;
        descriptorPoolRayTracing_ = device_.getLogicalDevice()->createDescriptorPoolUnique(descriptorPoolCreateInfo);
    }
   ```
4. Не забываем и про descriptor set layout

   ```
    // Макет размещения набора используемого в трассировке лучей
    {
        // Описание привязок
        std::vector<vk::DescriptorSetLayoutBinding> bindings = {
                // Структура ускорения верхнего уровня
                {
                        0,
                        vk::DescriptorType::eAccelerationStructureKHR,
                        1,
                        vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eRaygenKHR|vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eClosestHitKHR|vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eAnyHitKHR,
                        nullptr,
                },
                // Хранимое изображение, результат трассировки
                {
                        1,
                        vk::DescriptorType::eStorageImage,
                        1,
                        vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eRaygenKHR,
                        nullptr,
                },
                // Харнимый буфер индексов (массив дескрипторов)
                {
                    2,
                    vk::DescriptorType::eStorageBuffer,
                    static_cast<uint32_t>(maxMeshes),
                    vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eRaygenKHR|vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eClosestHitKHR|vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eAnyHitKHR,
                    nullptr
                },
                // Харнимый буфер вершин (массив дескрипторов)
                {
                    3,
                    vk::DescriptorType::eStorageBuffer,
                    static_cast<uint32_t>(maxMeshes),
                    vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eRaygenKHR|vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eClosestHitKHR|vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eAnyHitKHR,
                    nullptr
                },
                // Хранимый буфер матриц модели (массив дескрипторов)
                {
                    4,
                    vk::DescriptorType::eStorageBuffer,
                    static_cast<uint32_t>(maxMeshes),
                    vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eRaygenKHR|vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eClosestHitKHR|vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eAnyHitKHR,
                    nullptr
                }
        };

        // Создать макет размещения дескрипторного набора
        vk::DescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo{};
        descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo.bindingCount = bindings.size();
        descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo.pBindings = bindings.data();
        descriptorSetLayoutRayTracing_ = device_.getLogicalDevice()->createDescriptorSetLayoutUnique(descriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo);
   ```
5. Обновление (связка) дескрипторов и конкретных буферов в цикле (проходим по всем текущеим элементам сцены и связываем их буферы индексов, вершин и UBO с нужными дескрипторами)

   ```
   // Г е о м е т р и ч е с к и е  +  U B O  б у ф е р ы  м е ш е й

    std::vector<vk::DescriptorBufferInfo> indexBufferInfos;
    std::vector<vk::DescriptorBufferInfo> vertexBufferInfos;
    std::vector<vk::DescriptorBufferInfo> uboBufferInfos;

    for(auto & sceneMesh : sceneMeshes_)
    {
        indexBufferInfos.emplace_back(
                sceneMesh->getGeometryBuffer()->getIndexBuffer().getBuffer().get(),
                0,
                VK_WHOLE_SIZE);

        vertexBufferInfos.emplace_back(
                sceneMesh->getGeometryBuffer()->getVertexBuffer().getBuffer().get(),
                0,
                VK_WHOLE_SIZE);

        uboBufferInfos.emplace_back(
                sceneMesh->getModelMatrixUbo().getBuffer().get(),
                0,
                VK_WHOLE_SIZE);
    }

    vk::WriteDescriptorSet writeIndexBuffers{};
    writeIndexBuffers.setDstSet(rtDescriptorSet_.get());
    writeIndexBuffers.setDstBinding(2);
    writeIndexBuffers.setDstArrayElement(0);
    writeIndexBuffers.setDescriptorCount(static_cast<uint32_t>(indexBufferInfos.size()));
    writeIndexBuffers.setDescriptorType(vk::DescriptorType::eStorageBuffer);
    writeIndexBuffers.setPBufferInfo(indexBufferInfos.data());
    writes.push_back(writeIndexBuffers);

    vk::WriteDescriptorSet writeVertexBuffers{};
    writeVertexBuffers.setDstSet(rtDescriptorSet_.get());
    writeVertexBuffers.setDstBinding(3);
    writeVertexBuffers.setDstArrayElement(0);
    writeVertexBuffers.setDescriptorCount(static_cast<uint32_t>(vertexBufferInfos.size()));
    writeVertexBuffers.setDescriptorType(vk::DescriptorType::eStorageBuffer);
    writeVertexBuffers.setPBufferInfo(vertexBufferInfos.data());
    writes.push_back(writeVertexBuffers);

    vk::WriteDescriptorSet writeUboBuffers{};
    writeUboBuffers.setDstSet(rtDescriptorSet_.get());
    writeUboBuffers.setDstBinding(4);
    writeUboBuffers.setDstArrayElement(0);
    writeUboBuffers.setDescriptorCount(static_cast<uint32_t>(uboBufferInfos.size()));
    writeUboBuffers.setDescriptorType(vk::DescriptorType::eStorageBuffer);
    writeUboBuffers.setPBufferInfo(uboBufferInfos.data());
    writes.push_back(writeUboBuffers);


    // Связываем дескрипторы с ресурсами
    device_.getLogicalDevice()->updateDescriptorSets(writes.size(), writes.data(), 0, nullptr);
   ```
6. Убеждаемся что у всех буферов, которые используются в качестве таких SSBO есть флаг использования `vk::BufferUsageFlagBits::eStorageBuffer`

В итоге, в шейдере будет доступ ко всем необходимым данным, и можно будет интерполировать нужные атрибуты вершин при помощи барицентрических координат.

```
// ID текущего объекта
uint objId = gl_InstanceID;

// Матрица модели
mat4 modelMatrix = _matrices[objId].m;

// Матрица преобразования нормалей
mat3 normalMatrix = transpose(inverse(mat3(modelMatrix)));

// Индексы вершин в индексном буфере для треугольника, с которым произошло пересечение (gl_PrimitiveID - индекс треугольника)
ivec3 ind = ivec3(_indices[objId].i[3 * gl_PrimitiveID + 0],
                  _indices[objId].i[3 * gl_PrimitiveID + 1],
                  _indices[objId].i[3 * gl_PrimitiveID + 2]);

// Вершины треугольников в буфере вершин (достаем при помощи полученных индексов)
Vertex[3] vertices = Vertex[3](_vertices[objId].v[ind.x],
                               _vertices[objId].v[ind.y],
                               _vertices[objId].v[ind.z]);

// Интерполированное значение в точке пересечения
Vertex interpolated = interpolatedVertex(vertices, attribs);

// Перевести в глобальное пространство из пространства модели
interpolated.normal = normalize(normalMatrix * interpolated.normal);
interpolated.position = (modelMatrix * vec4(interpolated.position,1.0f)).xyz;
```

Есть еще такой момент, что слои валидации могут ругаться на то, что есть обращение к дескрипторам, для которых не делалось обновление. Это всё происходит потому что при создании descriptor set layout'а указывалось максимальное кол-во дескрипторов, а не то, которое фактически используется. Если там указать ровно столько, сколько будет использовано - то всё будет нормально. По сути это предупреждение слоёв можно игнорировать (либо создавать descriptor set layout с кол-вом дескрипторов соотвествующим кол-ву элементов сцены)

Может быть это кому-нибудь пригодится.